# Simplest way to create Common class for Get and Post request with function?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I want to create a common class for Get and Post request. And i want to create function in which i can pass (URL,Params,Type). When i implement this function i want to implement in sigle line like `function(URL,Params,Type - i.e POST or GET)`.
I tried to implement but it is very big process and implementation is very big. I want to minimize it.

> Note: I don't want to use any library. I want to use pure java code i.e HttpURLConnection.

Here is the code i tried.

**HttpCall**

```
public class HttpCall {

public static final int GET = 1;
public static final int POST = 2;

private String url;
private int methodtype;
private HashMap<String,String> params ;

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public int getMethodtype() {
    return methodtype;
}

public void setMethodtype(int methodtype) {
    this.methodtype = methodtype;
}

public HashMap<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}

public void setParams(HashMap<String, String> params) {
    this.params = params;
}
}
```

**HttpRequest**

```
public class HttpRequest extends AsyncTask<HttpCall, String, String> {

private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";
private Context context;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public HttpRequest(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Sending");
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(HttpCall... params) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    HttpCall httpCall = params[0];
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    try{
        String dataParams = getDataString(httpCall.getParams(), httpCall.getMethodtype());
        URL url = new URL(httpCall.getMethodtype() == HttpCall.GET ? httpCall.getUrl() + dataParams : httpCall.getUrl());
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod(httpCall.getMethodtype() == HttpCall.GET ? "GET":"POST");
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        if(httpCall.getParams() != null && httpCall.getMethodtype() == HttpCall.POST){
            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, UTF_8));
            writer.append(dataParams);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
        }
        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                response.append(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return response.toString();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    onResponse(s);
}

public void onResponse(String response){

}

private String getDataString(HashMap<String,String> params, int methodType) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean isFirst = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (isFirst){
            isFirst = false;
            if(methodType == HttpCall.GET){
                result.append("?");
            }
        }else{
            result.append("&");
        }
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), UTF_8));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), UTF_8));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
}
```

**And I have to implement it like this**

```
public void SendData(String input){
    HttpCall httpCallPost = new HttpCall();
    httpCallPost.setMethodtype(HttpCall.POST);
    httpCallPost.setUrl("https://ajaygohel012.000webhostapp.com/Test.php");
    HashMap<String,String> paramsPost = new HashMap<>();
    paramsPost.put("data",input);
    httpCallPost.setParams(paramsPost);
    new HttpRequest(this){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            super.onResponse(response);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }.execute(httpCallPost);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Helper Connection Class :**

```
package co.helper;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class HelperHttpConnection {

    private static HttpURLConnection httpConn;


    public static HttpURLConnection getRequest(String requestURL)
            throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);

        httpConn.setDoInput(true); // true if we want to read server's response
        httpConn.setDoOutput(false); // false indicates this is a GET request

        return httpConn;
    }

    public static HttpURLConnection postRequest(String requestURL,
                                                    Map<String, String> params) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);

        httpConn.setDoInput(true); 

        StringBuffer requestParams = new StringBuffer();

        if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {

            httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // true indicates POST request

            Iterator<String> paramIterator = params.keySet().iterator();
            while (paramIterator.hasNext()) {
                String key = paramIterator.next();
                String value = params.get(key);
                requestParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
                requestParams.append("=").append(
                        URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
                requestParams.append("&");
            }

            // sends POST data
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    httpConn.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(requestParams.toString());
            writer.flush();
        }

        return httpConn;
    }


    public static String readSingleLineRespone() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        if (httpConn != null) {
            inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Connection is not established.");
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                inputStream));

        String response = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();

        return response;
    }


    public static String[] readMultiLineRespone() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        if (httpConn != null) {
            inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Connection is not established.");
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                inputStream));
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();

        return (String[]) response.toArray(new String[0]);
    }


    public static void close() {
        if (httpConn != null) {
            httpConn.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo :**

```
package co.helper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HttpConnectionDemo{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // test sending GET request
        String requestURL = "http://www.facebook.com";
        try {
            HelperHttpConnection.getRequest(requestURL);
            String[] response = HelperHttpConnection.readMultiLineRespone();
            for (String line : response) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        HelperHttpConnection.close();


        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        requestURL = "https://facebook.com/";
        params.put("UserName", "your_email");
        params.put("Password", "your_password");

        try {
            HelperHttpConnection.postRequest(requestURL, params);
            String[] response = HelperHttpConnection.readMultiLineRespone();
            for (String line : response) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        HelperHttpConnection.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How to call it and get response? And why there is diff method for Single LineResponse & MultiLineResponse?

Comment: I have given demo  example along with it . have you checked that . You just need to update request param as per your requirement .

Comment: But this is  very long procedure to call it. It is not possible to call it in single line?

Comment: Check my code in question. It is even shorter than your answer.

Comment: Internally even third party libraries will be doing same thing . I thought you are looking for helper class  that's why I answered .  I am not comparing  code by lines .